# UI does not render after state is changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router

I have an app (project in Udacity) in `React` which display books on my shelves according to categories: *Currently Reading*, *Want to Read* and *Read*. Every time I change the category say from Want to Read to Currently Reading the book will move to the right category and in this case it would be Currently Reading. My code works on this one with no problem. However, you can also search from the vast library of books wherein you could move to your shelf, by default the category is None, although you could include the existing books in your shelf as part of being search (aside from the main library of books). Now, my problem is this, if I move from *None* to *Want To Read* category for example my UI does not change after I click the back button that brought me back to the main page (i.e. App.js). When I do however, change of category in the main, I have no problem. Also my function for updating the Book Shelf in *App.js* when called does not show any error in the console.

I have the following components:

```
 App
  |
  |--BooksSearch
  |--BooksList
  |     |--BookShelf
  |--BooksSearchPage
        |--BookShelf
```

The `BooksList` and `BooksSearch` displays the books and the search button respectively in the main page (i.e. App.js). The `BooksSearchPage` allows user to search books from the library to move into the shelves. The `BookShelf` displays the list of books whether they are in the shelves or in the library.

This is my **App.js**

```
class App extends React.Component {

 state = {
 mybooks : [], 
 showSearchPage: false
}

componentDidMount() { 
 BooksAPI.getAll().then( (mybooks)=> { 
    this.setState({mybooks})
 })}

toCamelShelf(Shelf) {
 if (Shelf==="currentlyreading") return "currentlyReading"
 if (Shelf==="wanttoread") return "wantToRead"
 return Shelf
}

updateBookShelf = (mybook, shelf) => {
shelf=this.toCamelShelf(shelf)
BooksAPI.update(mybook, shelf).then(
this.setState((state)=>({      
    mybooks: state.mybooks.map((bk)=>bk.id === mybook.id ? 
    {...bk, shelf:shelf} : bk)
 })))}

render() {
 return (
   <div className="app">
     {this.state.showSearchPage ? (
       <Route path='/search' render={({history})=>(
        <BooksSearchPage mybooks={this.state.mybooks} onSetSearchPage={
            ()=>{ this.setState({showSearchPage:false});
                  history.push("/");
              }}
              onUpdateBookShelf={this.updateBookShelf}
            />
      )} />
    ) : (
      <Route exact path='/' render={()=>(
        <div className="list-books">
          <div className="list-books-title">
            <h1>My Reads</h1>
          </div>
          <BooksList mybooks={this.state.mybooks} 
            onUpdateBookShelf={this.updateBookShelf}/>
          <BooksSearch onSetSearchPage={()=>this.setState({showSearchPage:true})}/>
        </div>
      )} />           
    )}
  </div>
  )
 }
}

export default App
```

And since the code is too long, I included my [repo](https://github.com/edper/readable-udacity) in Github. I am very new to `ReactJS` and have been debugging this problem for the last 3 days but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a hard time understanding the app enough to know why exactly, but it sounds like its a state issue.

If you navigate away and come back, or click something and it doesn't update properly, the state isn't being updated at that moment (that event) or the state wasn't saved correctly right before that event.

As soon as you reproduce the problem event, ask yourself "what was the state right before I did this?" and "why is the state how it is now?"

1. Did you forget to update the state?
2. Is it getting the wrong state from somewhere?
3. Did you call `this.setState({ something })`?
4. Did you overwrite the state instead of adding to it?
5. Is there a missing state update?

On both pages, right before and right after, add in the render method: `console.log(this.state)` and if needed, `console.log(this.props)`. I think you will see the problem if you look there. The question is how exactly did it get like that? Re-visit all your state updates.

If you navigate away and come back, where does it get that state from? Why is that data in there?

Remember, React is a state machine. State is an object that has a snapshot of data every time you look at it. It's like looking at a piece of paper with all your data on it. If you leave the room and come back and the data isn't there, what updated your state and made it go away? or why didn't it get added to your state? That mechanism there is causing your problem.

I see a few spots in your code to focus on:

```
BooksAPI.update(mybook, shelf).then(
this.setState((state)=>({      
    mybooks: state.mybooks.map((bk)=>bk.id === mybook.id ? 
    {...bk, shelf:shelf} : bk)
 })))}
```

and

```
<BooksSearchPage mybooks={this.state.mybooks} onSetSearchPage={
        ()=>{ this.setState({showSearchPage:false});
              history.push("/");
          }}
          onUpdateBookShelf={this.updateBookShelf}
```

and

```
<BooksList mybooks={this.state.mybooks} 
            onUpdateBookShelf={this.updateBookShelf}/>
          <BooksSearch onSetSearchPage={()=>this.setState({showSearchPage:true})}/>
```

also right up here:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
  mybooks : [], 
  showSearchPage: false
 }

componentDidMount() { 
 BooksAPI.getAll().then( (mybooks)=> { 
    this.setState({mybooks})
 })}
```

One of them is acting too strongly or one of them isn't updating at the right time, or data is getting overwritten, I suspect.

The `console.log()` should be most helpful. If your data is missing. Make it show up there at that time and the problem will go away :) (P.S. that setState on componentDidMount looks a little suspect).

Comment: First of all thank you for your response. I did a lot of `console.log` especially the `updateBookShelf` in **App.js**. I will surely try to do more `console.log` as you suggested from state to state or page to page (virtual it may). I don't believe though it's the `ComponentDidMount` since it works well so far, although I could be mistaken.

Comment: You mentioned something about adding books that were in the shelf, so it sounds like some kind of merging needs to occur, and it also definitely sounds like it could be regressing to an incorrect or older state.

Comment: Sprinkle a little console.log on it so you can say "hmm this isn't right" and look at the state then... and examine the event right before that. I feel strongly you can find where it's trolling you. Maybe even the component isn't re-rendering which is causing the state to not update (since you say you were navigating). I'd also recommend console.logging everything in play when it goes to set state. See if anything is anomalous. Like literally log everything if you have to. Get aggressive with the forensics while imagining how the data *must* flow.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions I appreciate it much.

Comment: I finally found the solution, I forgot to add the selected books from search/library on my local component because I thought all the while that when I update the API my method that updates my local component, will add the book when actually it just updates the book category.

Comment: Nice work. If you remember anything from me, make it the epic console.log spam, so you can view the 3 critical angles: *before* / *now* / *after*, like a ball bouncing. Here are the 3 angles in picture form: `\ _ /`. It's all just events and state in an immutable, stateless world.